# How can I take another variable from a def function and add it to another def function to get a new sum?

Tags: python, function, sum

```
def room1(phone_charge):
    phone_charge = 5
    import random
    randNum = random.randint(1,5)
    print("An outlet! You quickly plug in your phone, but the wiring in the house is faulty and soon shorts out.\n")
    positve = str(phone_charge + randNum)
    print("Your phone is now " + positve + " % charged\n")
    return(positve)
```

I need to add positive to another function

```
def room5(phone_charge):
    import random
    randomNUM = random.randint(1,30)
    
    positve2= str(phone_charge + randomNUM)
    print("Your phone is now " + positve2 + " % charged\n")
    return(positve2)
```

I need to add `postive` to the `room5` variable `postive2`

I tried returning variables and putting them in the next function but then my code that was written behind where I entered the returning variable it was no longer highlighted

Comment: `room5` should accept a second argument, which would be the return value of `room1`.

Comment: These should be one function with an additional parameter.  DRY -- don't repeat yourself.

Comment: Why are you assigning `phone_charge = 5` instead of using the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Since the two functions return their values, you can add them together after calling.

```
p1 = room1(phone_charge)
p5 = room5(phone_charge)

print(f"Total is {p1 + p5}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the two functions have the same functionality use one function with an extra parameter.

```
import random

def room(phone_charge, rand_range):
    randNum = random.randint(1,rand_range)
    print("An outlet! You quickly plug in your phone, but the wiring in the house is faulty and soon shorts out.\n")
    positve = str(phone_charge + randNum)
    print("Your phone is now " + positve + " % charged\n")
    return positve

room1 = room(5, 5)
room5 = room(10, 30)

total = room1 + room5
```